# User must exist error ruby user id not recognised

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to enter the user for my system to save in however everytime I do it tells me user must exist
[image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1whxJ.png)

I'm using devise to create the log in/create user function

the purchases controller:

```
   @purchase = @user.orders.all

   end

   # GET /purchases/new
  def new
  @users= User.find(current_user.id)
  @purchase = Purchase.new
  end 

  # GET /purchases/new
  def new
  @users= User.find(current_user.id)
  @purchase = Purchase.new
  end

  # POST /purchases
  # POST /purchases.json
  def create
  @purchase = Purchase.new(purchase_params)

   respond_to do |format|
   if @purchase.save
    format.html { redirect_to @purchase, notice: 'Purchase was successfully 
   created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @purchase }
   else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @purchase.errors, status: 
   :unprocessable_entity }
  end
  end
  end


  private
   # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
   def set_purchase
   @purchase = Purchase.find(params[:id])
   end
```

I've added the purchase param here
       # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
       def purchase_params
       params.require(:purchase).permit(:po_date, :users_id, :status)
       end
       end

Purchases controller

```
class Purchase < ApplicationRecord
def purchase_params
        params.require(:purchases).permit(:po_date, :user_id, :status)
end


has_many :raisingpurchases
belongs_to :user
end
```

User Controller

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

def users_params
  params.require(:users).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me)
end

has_many :purchases

end
```

Comment: Which controller method is this hitting?  Can you show that method?  Looks like you are showing new, which only handles creating the new, empty object, not save the object which is where this fail is happening.

Comment: I've updated to show where I'm saving and creating the purchases

Comment: Can you show the params , `purchase_params` method too?

Comment: added the purchase param

Answer (score 1):

1) You do not keep your user_params in user.rb. This is totally messed up! Same for purchase. I would advise you to first learn scaffloding and see how an MVC app should be structured.

2) purchases controller:

```
  def new
  @purchase = Purchase.new
  end

  def create
  @purchase = Purchase.new(purchase_params)
  @purchase.user_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
    #######


   def purchase_params
        params.require(:purchases).permit(:po_date, :status)
   end
```

You can remove user_id from purchase_params as it is set automatically in the `create`action.

Looking at your code, I'm not sure that you're even getting the current_user correctly from devise or another authentication solution.
For more details your console / complete code on git would be needed.

Better look here - an example of how what you want to do works in a real application:

https://github.com/yshmarov/pikaburuby/blob/master/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb

Comment: Hi I've updated, however I'm still getting the same error